# How to change parameter in file by first parameter

Tags: python, list, file

I have list:

```
312|fotelja snesko|bela|15|2900|fotelja|False
621|digimon tabure|crna|25|850|tabure|False
981|krevet trio|siva|8|5200|trosed|False
```

Program must change False to True by first parameter in line (code: 312,621...), and save it.

This is my code that just find code and change False to True.

```
parameter = input("code is: ")

someFile = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")
allDATA = someFile.readlines()
for line in allDATA:
    line = line.split("|")

    if parameter == line[0]:
        line[6] = "True"

        someFuncFORBACK()

print("wrong code!")
someFuncFORBACK()
```

My question is how i can rewrite ?

**EDIT:**

*File now:*

```
312|fotelja snesko|bela|15|2900|fotelja|False
621|digimon tabure|crna|25|850|tabure|False
981|krevet trio|siva|8|5200|trosed|False
```

Code is:>> 312

*File after:*

```
312|fotelja snesko|bela|15|2900|fotelja|True
621|digimon tabure|crna|25|850|tabure|False
981|krevet trio|siva|8|5200|trosed|False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, close the file after reading all lines:

```
with open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r") as someFile:
    allDATA = someFile.readlines()
```

Then after processing all lines in `sadrzaj`, you simply write one by one.

```
with open("komad_namestaja.txt", "w") as someFile:
    for line in sadrzaj:
        someFile.write('|'.join(line) + '\n')
```

Just be careful because each `line`, already has a `'\n'` character at the end. You better use strip to remove it.

```
for line in sadrzaj:
    line = line.strip().split("|")
```

Comment: i accidently confused you with sadrzaj and allDATA, it's same.

Comment: What exactly is the problem now?

Comment: I can't follow your problem, please post expected vs actual output

Comment: posted, file now and file after

Comment: From problem statement's *Program must change False to True by first parameter in line (code: 312,621...), and save it.* it seems correct. Do you want to only save the changed line?

Comment: i want to save changed line and other lines that wasn't changed